# How can I access these getPosition.x and getPosition.y values?

Tags: java, abstract

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. It's for a school assignment, our lector provided us with a ForestSimulation.java file, that calls for a tree.getPosition().x, as seen here:[image: tree.getPosition().x]

We are told to make the methods that are needed, so I've made a Tree class aswell as a Birch class.
[image][image]

Yet I feel that no matter how I declare the x and y-values I can't figure to make it work.

I've tried a non abstract getPosition, and calling this.x in the method body. I've tried (as in SS) to make it an abstract method. But nothing seems to work.

Please help <3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post images of text. Instead, copy and paste text into the question body. You may edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to match a call like

```
tree.getPosition().x
```

but the method you put into your Tree class is

```
void getPosition() { ... }
```

so this method will never return a point that has x and y coordinates. Change this method into

```
Point getPosition() { ... }
```